# The Scala script for node [ ScalaNode ] is invalid. Reason: [ No such struct field defaultSlot

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have below scala code, with error: The Scala script for node [ ScalaNode ] is invalid. Reason: [ No such struct field defaultSlot

We haven't created a schema separately and are building the jar

Scala code:

Wrap Lines

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, Row, SparkSession}
import com.zeen.TimberLogReadDEX._

object Delivery{

def readTimberManifest(spark: SparkSession, filepath: String): Dataset[Row] = {
    import com.amazon.spark.timber.SparkTimber._
    import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    import spark.implicits._

    val cdexTextFile = spark.timber.readManifest(filepath).map(row => {
      val list = new ListBuffer[String]()
      val index = row.indexOf(":")
      if (index > 0) {
        list += row.substring(index + 1, row.length);
      }
      list
    }).flatMap(row => row)
    val cdex = spark.read.json(cdexTextFile)
    val flatcdex =  cdex.withColumn("delivery", explode($"delivery"))
                       .withColumn("Options", explode($"delivery.Options"))
                       .withColumn("Items", explode($"delivery.Items"))
                      
    val cdexraw = flatcdex.select(

      col("customerId"),
      $"Options.defaultSlot".getItem(0).cast("string").alias("defaultSlotStartTime"),
      $"Options.defaultSlot".getItem(1).cast("string").alias("defaultSlotEndTime")

      )
    cdexraw
   }

}
```

Any help would be great.